# C++ operators on reference vars, what does this do?

Tags: c++

I ran across a class with a member var as a reference (to a std::istream), with operator void *() and bool operator  !() that return that reference, and i'm wondering what that would be for.  The class is related to reading/parsing text files with config param pairs. I've pulled out from the (much) larger project the basic parts.  In qt (MSVC 2015 community tool chain), i had to change the `operator void *()` to get a compile, but seems ok on the original linux system.

(In my desktop environment i get:  "error: C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::istream' to 'void *'", so i replaced with a call to `if(m_in.eof())` and `return nullptr`)

```
class LR { // (line reader)
public:
  LR(const std::string &filename);

  .... other stuff

  operator void *() const { return &m_in; }
  bool operator !() { return !m_in; }
  LR & operator>>(std::string &line);

private:
  std::istream &m_in; // input stream
  std::ifstream m_in_file; // input file (if specified)

}; 
LR::LR(const std::string &filename, ... other stuff) :
   : m_in(m_in_file)
{
   //  .... other stuff
  if(filename.size() > 0)
  {
    m_in_file.open(filename.c_str());
  }
   // .... other stuff
}
```

and the class that uses this:

```
class CR { // config reader
public:
  // .... other stuff
  void Load_Variable(const std::string &section, value, etc...);
private:
  LR m_reader;
};
void CR::Load_Variable(const std::string &section, value, etc.) {
  string line;
  bool found = false;
  while (m_reader >> line)
  {
    // .... check stuff, etc.
  }
}
```

Debugging in Qt, `while (m_reader >> line)` calls the operator void *().
My questions:
Why use a member var reference to a `std::istream` like this?
What's the purpose of returning the address of member var `&m_in` when it's always valid because it's a member var (or is this not true?)
Would `operator *()` of m_reader ever return false?  I've searched a bit online and not found any similar examples of this kind of use of operators on member var refs.  I need to look next at what it does when the file open fails.
Possibly this code originally used heap pointer vars or some other approach for the `m_in` var and it was changed somewhere along the way to be a normal member var, with the operators then edited to this? I think the history is not easy to get.
Thanks for the help, stackoverflow is awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The istream has a flag that indicates if an error has occurred and it overrides the ! operator for easy access. You'll often see it used like this:

```
myStream >> line;
if(!myStream)
   cout<<"Error reading data"<<endl;
```

So you are not returning a reference, you are returning a Boolean flag. Think of the ! operator as `isNoError()` accessor.

Your class is doing the same thing, just passing through the result from the stream it wraps.

The * operator is probably there as backward compatibility measure. Probably the existing code base is expecting a pointer and this was added so that the existing code base works with the new implementation.